# toggleClass not working when clicking on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I'm using `.toggleClass` to *hide/show* a *div* on my website, and it works as I want it, but only when I click on the div itself and not on its child elements (three *span*) so I have to click just on the div itself, but what I don't get is why it detects the click but does not execute the `toggleClass` when clicking on these spans ?

Html :

```
<div class="ClicLog Login" id="BoutonLogin">
    <span class="ico-Login"></span>
    <span class="noMobile" id="boutonConnectText">MON COMPTE</span>
    <span class="ico-Menu"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$('.ClicLog').click(function () {
    console.log("clic !");
    $('.nocollapse').toggleClass('LoginTest');
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: works just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcgg6nj8/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Not on my website :P

Comment: @GreySharr Something on your website not posted on your code makes it not working. You have to provide MCVE! Any other click event bound to these children? For testing purpose, try: `$('.ClicLog span').off('click');`, then check what happen now

Comment: can you share the page where it is not working

Comment: @GreySharr,  it works, as has been said, there must be something else making it not work? Try binding the clik event to the ID instead of the class? JS can throw some unexpected scenarios when trying to bind to a class thats used multiple times.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem : there was a javascript that closed the div I wanted to open when clicking somewhere else than the div only, so clicking on the spans opened and closed the div instantly... I thought that I checked it before but apparently not. Thanks all of you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem : there was a javascript that closed the div I wanted to open when clicking somewhere else than the div only, so clicking on the spans opened and closed the div instantly... I thought I checked it before but apparently not. Thanks all of you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the event handler only to the `div` and not its children.

Try this:

```
$('.ClicLog > span').click(function () {
    console.log("clic !");
    $('.nocollapse').toggleClass('LoginTest');
});
```

Comment: Ya but click event is supposed to bubble, by default

Comment: It's not working... The thing is that even when I click on the span, it detects the click and logs it in the console...

Comment: @GreySharr So just sounds like you are toggling class twice or something else in your logic is wrong

Comment: @A.Wolff In fact it detects one click, as the console logs only one ("clic !") per click ? I'm going to rebuild this and see what it does. Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: @GreySharr [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Don't let helpers having to guess what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

add span too

```
$('.ClicLog').children('span').click(function () {
    console.log("clic !");
    $('.nocollapse').toggleClass('LoginTest');
});
```

Comment: No, this would toggle the class twice

Comment: I changed it,Now What?

Comment: Now won't handle click on DIV, only if any child span is clicked

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('.ClicLog').on('click','*',function () {
    console.log("clic !");
    $('.nocollapse').toggleClass('LoginTest');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
you can use whatever selector you like with its second parameter.

```
$('.ClicLog').on('click', '*', function() {
  console.log("clic !");
  $('.nocollapse').toggleClass('LoginTest');
});
```

or

```
$('.ClicLog').on('click', '> *', function() {
  console.log("clic !");
  $('.nocollapse').toggleClass('LoginTest');
});
```

for direct descendents.

https://jsfiddle.net/x9tsv7bo/